# Creating some sort of list of C++ objects in C++/CLI

Tags: c++, list, c++-cli

I am trying to create a list/collection of C++ objects in C++/CLI and I have tried various ways but nothing seems to work (errors at compile time).

I have tried:

```
List<MyCppObject*> ^myList; //Does not allow non-.NET objects

ArrayList ^myList;
...
myList->Remove(myCppObject); //cannot convert parameter 1 from 'MyCppObject *' to 'System::Object ^'
```

**My requirements:**

1) The list MUST contain C++ objects

2) I need the ability to remove a particular object (e.g. vector won't work because it's only push/pop off top)

**Question:** How can I make a list/collection of C++ objects in a C++/CLI function work with the ability to easily remove a particular object?

Let me know if anyone would like some additional info; thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Nothing wrong with calling `std::vector<T>::erase()`, it's just not optimal in terms of performance if you do it a lot. Alternatively, `std::list<T>` has fast insert/erase anywhere and does not invalidate iterators.

Comment: `std::vector<T>::erase()` is O(N), just like the CLR `List<T>.RemoveAt()` and `ArrayList.RemoveAt()`, so if you're happy with List's performance characteristics, you'd be happy with vector's.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: no, it wouldn't be used a ton, so performance wise I suppose it would be ok. But as I see now, it only takes in an index as a parameter (not an object)? So I suppose I'd have to do my own search to find the index and then remove it?

Comment: @Kerrek SB & @Pete: Unfortunately std::vector isn't working for me. I put `std::vector<MyCppObject*> myList;` and got the following error: `error C4368: cannot define 'myList' as a member of managed 'MyNamespace::MyManagedClass': mixed types are not supported.` <sad face>

Comment: @developer : You never mentioned that this was intended to be a data member of a managed type. Obviously, that would have been useful to know... ;-]

Comment: @Pete: `std::list<T>::erase()` is O(1) (by iterator), while `list<T>::remove()` is linear (by value). More important than the insert/erase complexity are probably the invalidation guarantees for iterators and references. But anyway, the mixing between native and managed seems to be a more important issue! :)

Comment: @ildjarn: I didn't realize it was an important piece of the puzzle. However, apparently I can have a pointer to my native type! Therefore I no longer have an error when I compile. :) http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2204592/mixed-types-are-not-supported.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store native objects/pointers you must use native collection classes. If you want the collection class to maintain allocation/deallocation use `<MyCppObject>`, or use `<MyCppObject*>` if you would maintain the memory allocation (i.e. collection class would hold the pointers only).

STL/CLR classes would do something opposite - you can use STL classes for storing .NET objects.

Comment: What native collection classes would you suggest then? (That work similarly to List in .Net)

Comment: @developer : [`std::vector<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xd04bzs.aspx) is the direct native equivalent to `System::Collections::Generic::List<>`.

Comment: Apparently I can have a pointer to my native type! Therefore I no longer have an error. :) http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2204592/mixed-types-are-not-supported.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Its either `System::IntPtr` to unmanaged objects as in `List<System::IntPtr>^` or `std::list` (or your own c++ list) and then wrapper around that

**EDIT:**

You could do it like this

```
MyCppObject mynativeobj[10];
    System::Collections::Generic::List<System::IntPtr>^ mlist = gcnew System::Collections::Generic::List<System::IntPtr>();

    for(int i =0;i<10;i++)
    {
        mlist->Add(System::IntPtr((void*)&mynativeobj[i]));
    }
```

The only problem is that all the memory will still reside in the unmanaged part so if your vars go out of scope the `IntPtr`s won't be valid anymore. Also you need to free the memory under the pointers yourself

Comment: or `std::set`... or unordered container, could be STL or others like Google etc...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a managed container, you can use the native `list` type:

```
#include <list>

std::list<MyCppObject*> mylist;
// ...
mylist.remove(mycppobjptr);
```

Comment: `System::Collections::Generic::List` is not a linked list, it is a resizable array. Consequently, `std::vector<>` would be a better recommendation than `std::list<>`.

Comment: I receive the following error with this code however: error C4368: cannot define 'myList' as a member of managed 'MyNamespace::MyManagedClass': mixed types are not supported.

Comment: @developer: Aha. I was under the impression this was just a local variable. I guess this answer won't be much use to you then. :P

Comment: Apparently I can have a pointer to my native type! Therefore I no longer have an error. :) http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2204592/mixed-types-are-not-supported.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try

```
single object
MyCppObject^ _myCppObject = gcnew MyCppObject();

list of objects
List< MyCppObject ^>^ LIST = gcnew List< MyCppObject >();

add single element
LIST->Add( _myCppObject );

// remove single element
LIST->Remove( _myCppObject );

// these are all managed objects so when loss of scope it self destructs

// although such might be the case as per System::GC, you may still do...

LIST->Clear();

delete LIST;

LIST = nullptr;
```